# Why is the REG DELETE command failing in this batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I found a script to add Sublime Text into Explorer's context menu, but I no longer need this feature. I used a batch script when adding it to the the registry, and now when I try using the same script where `REG ADD` is replaced with `REG DELETE`, I get a syntax error.

This is the script; how can I correct this issue?

```
@echo off
SET st2Path=C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe

rem add it for all file types
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 2"   /f
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st2Path%,0" /f
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st2Path% \"%%1\"" /f

rem add it for folders
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2"         /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with Sublime Text 2"   /f
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2"         /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%st2Path%,0" /f
@reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%st2Path% \"%%1\"" /f
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/t` and `/d` options specify the type of value, and data within a value, respectively, when **creating** a new registry key.  They are not valid with `REG DELETE`.

The valid operations for `REG DELETE` (relevant to what you're trying to do) are:

### 1. Deleting an entire registry key:

```
REG DELETE HKLM\Sub\Key\Here
```

### 2. Deleting a specific value within a registry key:

```
REG DELETE HKLM\Sub\Key\Here /v ValueName
```

Comment: I tried changing the /t and /d to /v but still wouldnt work

Comment: @VisualExstasy You still misunderstand the problem.  Try running `REG DELETE /?` in your command prompt and reading the usage instructions carefully.

Comment: so the /f is needed but the /t and /d need to removed and replaced with /va ?

Comment: Nope. When deleting  a key just use `REG DELETE PATH\TO\KEY`.  If you just want to delete a specific value from a key, use `REG DELETE PATH\TO\KEY /v ValueName`.